# How to merge different documents into single one?

Tags: pdf, itext

Is there any way to merge word, excel documents into a PDF? I looked into iTextSharp but im not sure if it can do that. I have a requirement where user will upload word, excel document and i have merge them into a PDF document.

Comment: I think that if there are libraries to convert them separately you could probably merge them with a general pdf library.

Comment: are there any libraries available to convert word,excel into PDF. Can i use MS Office 2010 PIA to do this job?

Comment: I don't do C# but this might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/891531/convert-xls-doc-files-to-pdf-with-c

Answer (score 2):

Step 1) Convert your files to PDF.

Step 2) Merge the PDFs with PdfCopy.

Most Office formats can be converted to PDF (for free) via OpenOffice.org calls.  There are probably some service sites out there that can do the same, and various commercial software packages.  Vichle's link in his comment will probably do the trick.

Vichle's link also demonstrates that you probably didn't search SO first before asking your question.  Naughty naughty.

Merging PDFs is fairly trivial:

```
Document doc = new Document();
PdfCopy copy = new PdfCopy(doc, outputStream);
doc.open();

String paths[] = getPaths();
for (int i = 0; i < paths.length; ++i) {
  PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(paths[i]);

  /**** The first page is ONE, not zero ****/
  for (int j = 1; j <= reader.getNumberOfPages(); ++j) { 
    PdfImportedPage curPg = copy.getImportedPage(reader, j);
    copy.addPage(curPg);
  }
}

doc.close();
```

That's Java, but to convert to C# you really just need to switch the function names to upper case, and tweak a couple class names.  It's trivial.

And supporting evidence that C# is just MS's pet Java.

Comment: I searched SO first :):). BTW it looks like its not going to be a one step solution. There are Office PIA to convert word to PDF but Microsoft does not recommend them to use on Server. So first step is to convert Word to PDF and then merge them using iTextSharp. To convert word and excel to PDF i probably have to use SharePoint 2010 Automation Services or OpenOffice or aspose.com. unless you guys have any other solution

Answer (score 1):

I would like to share with you that you can [merge multiple PDF files into a single PDF file using Aspose.Pdf.Kit for .NET](http://www.aspose.com/documentation/.net-components/aspose.pdf.kit-for-.net/concatenate-pdf-documents.html).

If you also want to convert other office documents to PDF files, in your C# application, you can try [Aspose.Total for .NET product suite](http://www.aspose.com/categories/.net-components/aspose.total-for-.net/default.aspx). Aspose.Total for .NET allows you to convert Word, Excel, Powerpoint, Text, HTML and Image files to PDF format.

I hope this helps.

Disclosure: I work as Developer Evangelist at Aspose.

Answer (score 0):

Also, you can use PDFCombineProX at https://www.coolutils.com/PDFCombineProXNET

```
string src="C:\\test\\test1.docx".Chr(13)."C:\\test\\test2.xlsx";
string dest="C:\\test\\DestCombine.PDF";

PDFCombineProX Cnv = new PDFCombineProX();
Cnv.Convert(src, dest, "-c PDF -log c:\\Combine.log");

MessageBox.Show("Combine complete!");
```

Answer (score -2):

using  dev express RichEditDocumentServer class  you can merge multiple document in some easy step

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ASq0j.png)

Comment: Please don't put code in a screenshot. Code is text, just put the text in your answer.