# Merge two pdf memorystreams from PDFStampers into one memorystream w/ 2 pages

Tags: java, pdf, merge, itext, memorystream

This is my first experience with iText5 for .NET, and so far has been quite successful, except for one task.

I have created two VB.Net classes, each which successfully returns a valid MemoryStream containing a single page PDF document that can individually be returned to the browser and displayed, as well as attached and sent via email.

I would like to know how to merge the two streams into one stream containing a two page document, so that I could send the document as a single attachment return the stream to the browser to display one document containing both pages.

This code would be used in my code-behind page to return and email the content after creation. As you can see in the code attached, I would like to supply a single stream that contains a separate page for each current document.  In the code below the identifier `EitherSingleStream` shows where I have plugged each stream in individually and the code works for that single page.

Some of the code may be redundant, its my first iText5 for .NET outing, and any help would be greatly appreciated. Code I have so far is as follows.

```
Private Sub btnSubmit_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSubmit.Click
    Dim Emplid As String = txtEMPLID.Text,
        BankInfo As String = txtBankInfo.Text,
        AsOfDate As String = Request.Form("AsOfDate")

    lEmp = New VOELibrary.Employee(Emplid)

    lEmp.EarningsAsOfDate = AsOfDate
    lEmp.EarningsYears = 3
    lEmp.LoadEarningsSummary()
    lEmp.LoadEmploymentHistory()

    ' request logging meta data object
    Dim FormRequest As New VOELibrary.FormRequest

    ' Function that uses first template and Styamper to return first document stream
    Dim FM1005 As New VOELibrary.FannieMae1005(lEmp, BankInfo, UserInfo)
    Dim streamForm1005PDF As MemoryStream = FM1005.PDFStream

    ' Function that uses second template and stamper to return second docuemnt stream
    Dim VOESummary As New VOELibrary.VOESummary(lEmp, UserInfo)
    Dim streamVOESummaryPDF As MemoryStream = VOESummary.PDFStream

    *EitherSingleStream*.Position = 0

    MailPDF(*EitherSingleStream*, FormRequest)

    *EitherSingleStream*.Position = 0

    Dim response As HttpResponse = HttpContext.Current.Response
    response.Clear()
    response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename= FM1005.pdf")
    response.ContentType = "application/pdf"
    response.BinaryWrite(*EitherSingleStream*.ToArray())
    response.Flush()
    response.End()

    With FormRequest
        .Req_UID = UserInfo(0).ToString
        .Req_UserName = UserInfo(1).ToString
        .EMPID = lEmp.EmplID
        .FormDate = Date.Now.ToShortDateString
        .Requestor = BankInfo
        .AsOfDate = AsOfDate
        .Log()
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: It's not clear what the question is.

Answer (score 1):

You would modify the functions to Return a PdfPage rather than a Whole Document and then combine the pages in another function and output the MemoryStream after you combined them.

That or you would make a function to take an array of Documents and then for each PdfPage in the Document you would add a new page to a new document and return that.

See [How to merge different documents into single one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5941715/how-to-merge-different-documents-into-single-pdf?rq=1)