# Merge 2 PDFs in Java

Tags: java, pdf, itext

I have a Problem with iText and merging of 2PDFs to 1 PDF.

I would like to merge this PDFs:

PDF1 - One Site:

> This is PDF1.

PDF2 - One Site:

> This is PDF2.

What I need: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/4001370/whatIneed.pdf

Code 1 - Two Sites:

> One Site One: This is PDF1.
>   One Site Two: This is PDF2.

```
    PDFMergerUtility ut = new PDFMergerUtility();
    ut.addSource("C:\\Temp\\PDF1.pdf");
    ut.addSource("C:\\Temp\\PDF2.pdf");
    ut.setDestinationFileName("C:\\Temp\\Code1.pdf");
    ut.mergeDocuments();
```

Code 2 - The number is overwritten:

> This is PDF(1/2).

```
public class main {
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, DocumentException {
    PdfReader reader;
    PdfImportedPage page;


    LinkedList<File> fileList = new LinkedList<File>();
    fileList.add(new File("C:\\Temp\\PDF1.pdf"));
    fileList.add(new File("C:\\Temp\\PDF2.pdf"));


    File ergebnis = new File("C:\\Temp\\Code2.pdf");
    Document document2 = new Document(PageSize.A4);
    PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document2, new FileOutputStream(ergebnis));

    document2.open();
    PdfContentByte canvas = writer.getDirectContent();

    // Header 
    reader = new PdfReader(fileList.get(0).getAbsolutePath());
    page = writer.getImportedPage(reader, 1);
    canvas.addTemplate(page, 0, 0);
    // Aufgabe
    reader = new PdfReader(fileList.get(1).getAbsolutePath());
    for(int i=1; i<=reader.getNumberOfPages(); i++){
        page = writer.getImportedPage(reader, i);
        canvas.addTemplate(page, 0, 0);
        document2.newPage();
    }

    document2.close();
    writer.close();
}
```

}

I have no Idea. I hope you can help me at this problem.

Comment: Is it clear that all of page 1 plus all of page 2 together fit on a single target page? In that case you have to merely adjust the numeric parameters of `canvas.addTemplate(page, 0, 0);`

Answer (score 3):

Please read [Chapter 6](http://manning.com/lowagie2/samplechapter6.pdf) of my book. It explains why using `PdfWriter`/`PdfImportedPage` is the wrong way to merge documents. You should use `PdfCopy` or `PdfSmartCopy` if you want to concatenate two documents. You should use `PdfStamper` if you want one document to act as *company stationery* for the other document. From your question, it's not clear which one of both you need (you leave that open to interpretation), so please read chapter 6. I've done the effort of writing it and making available for free so that you can choose the solution that is right for you.

Comment: I gather the asker wants to put the contents of the two source documents on the same result page **one under the other,** thus PdfCopy might not be the solution.

Comment: That's why I added the remark about PdfStamper and the company stationery.

Comment: Jep i need both documents on one result Page. Thanks for the Chapter about iText. I read it, but i can't concatenate my two pdf to one pdf on one site.

Comment: Define "on one site". What does the word site refer to in this context?

Comment: Also, the word "concatenate" is probably wrong. I guess you mean to say "superimpose". Please rephrase so that the question is more accurate. Please don't expect people to give accurate answers to inaccurate questions.

Comment: No i don'tmean "superimpose". The "superimpose-Example" is my Code2 :/ I mean this: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/4001370/pdf.png

Comment: The text of PDF2 is directly under the text of PDF1. Sorry for my bad english btw...

Comment: Your English is good, but you're making wrong assumptions about the Portable Document Format. You've read chapter 6, but you didn't grasp that PDF isn't a Word processing format. All content on a page has fixed coordinates, and you're assuming you can change those coordinates easily. You could by doing something like canvas.addTemplate(page, 0, -18); but how will you determine the Y value (I chose -18 arbitrarily based on your image). The problem isn't your knowledge of English; the problem is your knowledge of PDF (or the lack of it).

Answer (score 1):

The question is a bit vague - if you are asking how to take two PDFs and merge them together, this SO article shows the easiest way to do it in iText: [How to merge different documents into single one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5941715/how-to-merge-different-documents-into-single-one)